# Rotated strings wrapping inside Item of Pane, vs their ItemSize or "ImageSize" spec

Tags: grid-layouts

Why in this:

```
Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], ItemSize -> {2, 10}]}}, Frame -> True]
```

or this

```
Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], {59, 300}]}}, Frame -> True]
```

the text length is still wrapped based on the horizontal dimension?

[image]

**UPDATE**

To reinforce my comment, lets try something more close to the unfortunate complexity of the real world:

```
Grid[{{Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}]}}, Frame -> True]
```

vs

```
Grid[{{Item[Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}], ItemSize -> {2, 10}]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

So, I think you can see that placing `Rotate` before, instead of after, is probably not an universal solution.

**PS:** and many of these difficulties would not be there if `Grid` was intrinsically completed with what was added with Pane... like the possibility of limiting in height and not only in width, the `ImageSizeAction`, or better, `ItemSizeAction`, or both...
(since there is the `Scaled`, couldn't there be a `Imaged` and an `Itemed` equivalent?)

Comment: Use, e.g., `Grid[{{Rotate[Pane["this is a long text example", {300, 59}], Pi/2]}},
  Frame -> True]`... think about it.

Comment: @ciao Sure. But there seems to be nothing wrong with the two posted ways. I can see that there are many ways of doing the same thing, but they should be doing the same thing, shouldn't they? Should we always try to guess which way works, even if they are both sound?

Comment: @ciao please see my updated examples

Comment: for the second and fourth examples `Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2],  ItemSize -> {{2}, 10}]}}, Frame -> True]` and `Grid[{{Item[ Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}],  ItemSize -> {{2}, 10}]}}, Frame -> True]` seems to work.

Comment: @kguler 50% done! Don't you want to add as an answer? Could we conclude it from the documentation, or is this solution an unexpected side effect correcting the original side effect?

Comment: ... and  for the second example: `Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], {{Automatic}, 300},   Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: @kguler 100% done!

Answer (score 3):

Example 1:

```
Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], 
      ItemSize -> {#, 10}]}}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
 {2, {2}, {200}, {}, All, {All}, Full, {Full}, Automatic, 
  {Automatic}, haha, {haha, haha}}
```

[image]

Comparing with the case where `ItemSize` is not specified (i.e. it takes the default setting), it seems that the width is set to the default value in all these cases:

```
{Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2]]}}, Frame -> True], 
 Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2],  ItemSize -> {All, 10}]}}, 
   Frame -> True]}
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], {#, 300}, 
      Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
 {59, {300}, All, {All}, {Full}, Automatic, {Automatic}, {59, Automatic}}
```

[image]

Again, in comparison with the default value of `ItemSize`:

```
{Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], 
     Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True], 
 Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], 
     {{Automatic}, 300}, Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True]}
```

[image]

Using the setting `ImageSize -> {{59, 300}, 300}` gives what is expected in this example:

```
Grid[{{Pane[Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], 
    ImageSize -> {{59, 300}, 300}, Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Example 3:

```
Grid[{{Item[Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}], 
      ItemSize -> {#, 10}]}}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
 {2, {200}, {}, Full, {Full}, All, {All}, Automatic, 
  {Automatic}, haha, {haha, haha}}
```

[image]

versus the default setting for `ItemSize`:

```
{Grid[{{Item[Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}], 
     Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True], 
 Grid[{{Item[Row[{Rotate["this is a long text example", Pi/2], "haha"}], 
     ItemSize -> {All, 10}, Alignment -> Center]}}, Frame -> True]}
```

[image]

Changing `ItemSize -> {#, 10}` to `ItemSize -> {#, 40}`, and adding `Alignment -> Center`:
[image]

Comment: ... all this leaves me more inclined to use the approach suggested by @ciao in the comments above.

Comment: When it is possible, right? Or is it always possible? Did you figured out if this findings were possible from the documentation? Thank you for all this clarifications.

Comment: @P.Fonseca, I thought the usage `ImageSize->{{minwidth, maxwidth}, {minheight, maxheight}}` (from the docs on `ImageSize`) would work here.; and  it does if we set the maxwidth high enough to get the rotated text fit inside. But afaik  we can't do a similar thing with `ItemSize` settings.